# Удаление и обнуление EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Не понимаю в чем проблема.

```
if(delivery.Visit != null)
{
    delivery.Visit = null;
    _context.Deliveries.Update(delivery);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

В итоге объект остается привязанным. Visit - это так же объект из контекста. В БД в таблице deliveries поле Visit_id может быть null.

Comment: тогда может `delivery.Visit_Id = null;`?

Comment: @tym32167 так нету же такого свойства, есть свойство-обьект Visit

Comment: а вот эта `delivery` - вы её как получили? Из БД вытянули? Тем же контекстом?

Comment: @tym32167 нет, создал из формы.

Comment: тогда, наверное, надо вызывать чтьо то типа `_context.Deliveries.Attach(delivery)` перед тем, как делать update

Comment: @tym32167 вы правы, сработало!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед Update вызываем Attach и всё будет хорошо

```
_context.Deliveries.Attach(delivery);
....
_context.Deliveries.Update(delivery);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```