# Объясните пожалуйста, как работает Update в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-core

Я не понимаю, как работать с Entity Framework. После Laravel и его ОРМ мне это кажется совершенно недружелюбной технологией с кучей граблей. У меня есть сущность (модель):

```
    public class Funnel
    {
        public int FunnelId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public List<AdvertiserFunnel> AdvertiserFunnels { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsChoiceAllApps { get; set; }
        public List<string> PackageIds { get; set; }
        public List<PushTemplate> PushTemplates { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public Funnel()
        {
            CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }
```

Как видите, есть связи один-ко-многим (например, `Category`), есть многие-ко-многим (`AdvertiserFunnels`).

У меня есть репозиторий. С чистым контекстом в контроллерах я не работаю, вот метод сохранения:

```
        public void Save(Funnel funnel)
        {
            if (funnel.FunnelId == 0)
            {
                _applicationDbContext.Funnels.Add(funnel);
            }
            else
            {
                _applicationDbContext.Funnels.Update(funnel);
            }

            _applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Я делаю Update. И у меня есть два варианта. Вот первый, где я обновляю поле `IsActive`. Это банальный чекбокс на UI, при активации которого отправляется ajax на такой метод:

```
 public IActionResult SwitchActiveState([FromBody] JObject json)
        {
            int funnelId;
            bool isActive;
            try
            {
                funnelId = json.SelectToken("templateId").ToObject<int>();
                isActive = json.SelectToken("isActive").ToObject<bool>();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var item =
                _funnelRepository.Funnels
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FunnelId == funnelId);

            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            item.IsActive = isActive;

            _funnelRepository.Save(item);

            return Ok();
        }
```

Запускаю все это, вызываю обновление и все работает.

А теперь, я хочу обновить поле `AdvertiserFunnels`. Это уже форма редактирования, где у меня есть select multiple для данного поля. 
Вот такой код на обновление:

```
 public IActionResult Save([FromBody] FunnelViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var advertisersTask = _advertiserRepository.Advertisers
                .Where(x => viewModel.Advertisers.Select(y => y.AdvertiserId).Contains(x.AdvertiserId)).ToListAsync();

            var categoryTask = _categoryRepository.Categories
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => viewModel.Category.CategoryId == x.CategoryId);

            Task.WhenAll(advertisersTask, categoryTask);

            var advertisers = advertisersTask.Result;
            var category = categoryTask.Result;

            if (!advertisers.Any())
            {
                ModelState.TryAddModelError("Advertisers", "Нет ни одного рекла");
            }

            if (category == null)
            {
                ModelState.TryAddModelError("Category", "Необходимо выбрать категорию");
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var advertisersFunnels = new List<AdvertiserFunnel>();

            var funnel = new Funnel();
            funnel.Category = category;
            funnel.IsActive = viewModel.IsActive;
            funnel.IsChoiceAllApps = viewModel.IsChoiceAllApps;
            funnel.Title = viewModel.Title;
            funnel.PackageIds = viewModel.Applications.Select(x => x.AppId).ToList();
            funnel.FunnelId = viewModel.FunnelId;

            foreach (var advertiser in advertisers)
            {
                advertisersFunnels.Add(new AdvertiserFunnel
                {
                    Funnel = funnel,
                    Advertiser = advertiser,
                });
            }

            funnel.AdvertiserFunnels = advertisersFunnels;

            _funnelRepository.Save(funnel);

            return Ok();
        }
```

Запускаю обновление и:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ладно, думаю, может так надо в репозитории написать:

```
...
            else
            {
                _applicationDbContext.AdvertiserFunnels.AttachRange(funnel.AdvertiserFunnels);
                _applicationDbContext.Funnels.Update(funnel);
            }
...
```

Возвращаюсь на свой чекбокс (о котором речь шла ранее), тыкаю и:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да что ж такое. Может так надо:

```
 else
            {
                if (funnel.AdvertiserFunnels != null)
                {
                    _applicationDbContext.AdvertiserFunnels.AttachRange(funnel.AdvertiserFunnels);
                }

                _applicationDbContext.Funnels.Update(funnel);
            }
```

Тыкаю - работает. Я что то не так пишу? Почему так много проверок и каких-то безумных костылей получается? Я покажу, как это выглядело бы в Laravel (это php-фреймворк, если меня читают матерые дотнетчики и такие господа просто не знают про существование какого-то Laravel). Итак:

```
$funnel = Funnel::where('id', '=', $funnelId); // $funnelId, допустим, я получил из реквеста и это int

$funnel->isActive = true;
$funnel->save();
```

Все. Это первый случай. И все работает! Теперь многие-ко-многим:

```
$funnel = Funnel::where('id', '=', $funnelId);
$funnel->advertisers()->sync($arrayWithAdvertisersIds);
```

, где `advertisers()` - это метод, устанавливаемый в модели `Funnel` чтоб показать ОРМ, что это отношение многие-ко-многим. А `$arrayWithAdvertisersIds` это массив int идентификаторов сущности `Advertiser`, допустим, полученных из реквеста. Ну разве не более френдли? Кто что думает? Прошу покритиковать мой код и буду благодарен за дельные замечания, которые смогли бы упростить жизнь читающим. Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Как вы планируете в реляционной бд сохранять в это? `public List<string> PackageIds { get; set; }`

Comment: Вы показали не все ваши модели, контекст не показали совсем. В вашем примере на пхп вы делаете только обновление, а в коде на c# у вас добавление, в чем смысл такого сравнения?

Comment: Ну и вообще сравнивать пхп и ef по моему некорректно.

Comment: Увидел, что вы не создаете, а вроде как обновляете funnel. Почему в пхп вы его их бд тянете, а в дотнете просто создаете? Получите его тоже их бд

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework реализует паттерн *Единица работы* (*Unit of Work*, *UoW*). Его назначение — представлять бизнес-транзакции на уровне предметной области (не на уровне доступа к данным).

*Единица работы* сохраняет набор изменений, например, добавление, изменение и удаление записей. Все изменения вносятся в базу при вызове метода `SaveChanges`. Копии записей БД хранятся в единице работы в одном из нескольких состоянии: не изменённые, изменённые, новые и удалённые.

Такой подход очень удобен в некоторых сценариях, но накладывает определённые ограничения. Мы не можем просто удалить записи в базе. Мы должны их *загрузить* и пометить, как удалённые. В некоторых случаях можно сконструировать запись в *Единице работы* и пометить её, как будто она загружена из базы, после чего "удалить".

Такое может потребоваться, если вы реализуете сложную логику, или пытаетесь оптимизировать доступ к данным. Моя рекомендация: для начала сделать простое работающее решение, а потом, если скорость действительно будет низкой, разбираться с записями на низком уровне.

Итак, простой способ что-то сделать с существующей записью — сначала её загрузить.

**Удаление**

```
    public IAsyncResult DeleteById(int id)
    {
        var record = dbContext.Funnels.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (record == null)
            return NotFound();

        dbContext.Funnels.Remove(record);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        . . .
    }
```

**Обновление**

```
    public IAsyncResult UpdateById(int id, FunnelModel model)
    {
        var record = dbContext.Funnels.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (record == null)
            return NotFound();

        record.Foo = model.Foo;
        record.Bar = model.Bar;
        record.Baz = model.Baz;

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        . . .
    }
```

Обратите внимание, что при обновлении вам не надо явно помечать запись изменённой, то есть явно взывать `Update`. EF при загрузке из базы сохраняет её в состоянии "без изменений", а перед сохранением самостоятельно ищет все изменённые записи.

Если вам кажется, что это медленно — загружать записи чтобы их удалить или обновить, то вы правы. *Unit of Work* не про скорость работы, а про удобство при определённых сценариях.

При создании записи мы ничего не читаем, мы просто вызываем метод `Add`:

**Создание**

```
    public IAsyncResult Create(FunnelModel model)
    {
        dbContext.Records.Add(new Funnel
        {
            Foo = model.Foo,
            Bar = model.Bar,
            Baz = model.Baz,
        });

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        . . .
    }
```

В этом сценарии возможны проблемы с коллизиями записей. Если у вас суррогатный ключ, значение которого генерируется в БД, обычно всё нормально. Но если значением ключа управляете вы сами, вы можете попытаться записать в базу что-то, что там уже хранится.

Такой сценарий часто возникает при попытке добавить или изменить запись, доступную через навигационное свойство.

```
        var record = dbContext.Funnels.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (record == null)
            return NotFound();

        record.AdvertiserFunnels.Add(new AdvertiserFunnel { . . . });
```

Здесь мы загружаем запись `Funnel` из базы, но не загружаем связанные с ней записи `AdvertiserFunnels`. Мы создаём новую связанную запись, и, возможно это приведёт к ошибке. Например, EF может удалить старые записи, поскольку их нет в его образе базы.

Большим плюсом *Единицы работы* и конкретно EF является то, что он позволяет работать с группой записей, как с единым целым. В DDD есть понятие *агрегат* — это такой сложный объект, состоящий из нескольких простых сущностей, которые отображаются на таблицы.

Чтобы избегать проблем, надо попросить EF загружать основную запись `Funnel` вместе с навигационными свойствами, которые мы планируем изменить. Делается это с помощью метода `Include`.

```
        var record = dbContext.Funnels
                              .Include(x => x.AdvertiserFunnels)
                              .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (record == null)
            return NotFound();

        record.AdvertiserFunnels.Add(new AdvertiserFunnel { . . . });
```

Теперь EF точно знает, какие дочерние записи лежат в базе и может безболезненно создать новую.

Насколько я понимаю, ошибка в вашей программе возникает как раз из-за того, что в `dbContext` не загружаются навигационные свойства.

**UPDATE**

Подробнее напишу про уровни. В классических трёхзвенных приложениях уровень предметной области зависел от уровня доступа к данным. В результате, чтобы загрузить сущности, вы прямо на уровне предметной области, например в коре какого-нибудь сервиса, лезли в базу:

```
class FooService
{
   public void MakeSomething()
   {
       using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
       using (var command = connection.CreateCommand();
       {
           . . .
           using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
           {
               var foo = Foo.CreatFromDataReader(dataReader);
               . . .
           }
       }
   }
}
```

У этого кода две проблемы. Первая в том, что предметная область теперь завязана на SQL. Обычно этот аргумент не принимают, часто ли приходится менять нижний уровень? Мой опыт подсказывает, что да, приходится, но не часто.

Вторая проблема в том, что классы предметной области начинают слишком много знать про детали хранения. Эта информация им не нужна, но мы не можем без неё обходится. Класс `Foo` должен знать про `System.Data.IDataReader` и должен уметь себя оттуда читать.

Если нам потребуется транзакция, то мы сможем сделать её непосредственно для SQL-подключения.

Инвертировав зависимость, и введя интерфейс репозитория, мы уберём эти детали с уровня предметной области. Репозиторий — это большое хранилище наших сущностей, которое не помещается в память — такого знания достаточно на уровне предметной области.

Всё здорово, но методы репозитория могут обеспечивать атомарность и согласованность только на уровне отдельных агрегатов.

> Агрегаты — это составные сущности. Скажем, заказ в магазине в базе хранится в двух таблицах: сам заказ и его позиции. Но на уровне кода Java/C#/Python у вас будет один агрегат, корневой сущностью которого будет заказ, и кроме заказа там будут ещё сущности-позиции заказа.

Репозиторий заказа может внести несколько правок в один заказ в рамках одной транзакции. А что делать, если у нас есть сценарий, где задействованы разные агрегаты?

Понятно, где это делать — если у нас несколько аграгатов, которыми мы оперируем, значит, у нас какой-то бизнес-сценарий. Для бизнес-сценариев мы заводим классы служб (классы сервисов). Но не создавать же там `SqlTransaction` вручную?

Чтобы спрятать транзакцию как раз и используют паттерн `Unit of Work`. Его интерфейс (как и интерфейсы репозиториев), описан на уровне предметной области. Реализация делается ниже — на уровне доступа к данным.

Что касается *контроллеров*, то они находятся над уровнем предметной области. Это уровень взаимодействия с пользователем или взаимодействия с внешней программой. Классическое название — уровень представления.

Comment: `Мы не можем просто удалить записи в базе. Мы должны их загрузить и пометить, как удалённые.` Есть же [Attach](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/989305/179763) операция, не обязательно грузить данные из БД

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. У меня вопрос. "Его назначение — представлять бизнес-транзакции на уровне предметной области (не на уровне доступа к данным)." - то есть, на уровне репозитория, не на уровне контроллера? Контроллер - уровень доступа к данным, правильно я понял?

Comment: И еще вопрос, если есть опыт работы с NHibernate, поделитесь, там так же дела обстоят? Или она реализует другой паттерн?

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak Дописал про уровни прямо в ответ. Про NHibernate ничего сказать не могу, пользовался им давно и недолго.