# Невозможно удалить объект, поскольку он не был найден в ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Только начинаю взаимодействие с БД в С#, наткнулся вот на такую проблему, версия EF 6.2.0. Пробовал делать вторым способом, та же самая ошибка
1 способ

```cs
using (Model1 m = new Model1())
{
    var clients = ClientsGrid.SelectedItem as Clients;
    m.Clients.Remove(clients);
    m.SaveChanges();
    ClientsGrid.ItemsSource = m.Clients.ToList();
}
```

2 способ

```cs
{
    var clients = ClientsGrid.SelectedItem as Clients;
    Class1.Context.Clients.Remove(clients);
    Class1.Context.SaveChanges();
    ClientsGrid.ItemsSource = Class1.Context.Clients.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте код текстом, а не картинкой. КОгда код представлен текстом, его легче читать, можно скопировать, и провести по нему поиск.

Comment: Хорошо, могу изменить щас на текст если нужно

Comment: Попробуйте добавить Attach по [примеру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/989305/179763)

Comment: как вариант попробуйте вместо `var clients = ClientsGrid.SelectedItem as Clients;` написать `var clients = new Clients { Id =  ClientsGrid.SelectedItem.Id };` (предполагаю, что первичный ключ у вас в обоих классах назван Id -- но вообще-то хорошо было бы приложить код этих классов к запросу). В общем-то суть проблемы понятна и вам решение в предыдущем комментарии рабочее: класс в гриде - это Clients, поэтому в obj state эти объекты хоть и привелись но воспринимаются как detached сущности.